# Google AppEngine Indexing Delay

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Am trying to deploy a app to Google AppEngine. But the DataStore index building seems to take forever. The contents of my index.yaml

```
indexes:

# AUTOGENERATED

# This index.yaml is automatically updated whenever the dev_appserver
# detects that a new type of query is run.  If you want to manage the
# index.yaml file manually, remove the above marker line (the line
# saying "# AUTOGENERATED").  If you want to manage some indexes
# manually, move them above the marker line.  The index.yaml file is
# automatically uploaded to the admin console when you next deploy
# your application using appcfg.py.

- kind: comments
  properties:
  - name: content_type_id
  - name: is_public
  - name: is_removed
  - name: object_pk
  - name: site_id
  - name: created

- kind: comments
  properties:
  - name: content_type_id
  - name: object_pk
  - name: user_email
  - name: user_name
  - name: user_url
  - name: created

- kind: content_type
  properties:
  - name: app_label
  - name: name

- kind: pages
  properties:
  - name: post_status
  - name: created

- kind: pages
  properties:
  - name: post_status
  - name: post_title

- kind: posts
  properties:
  - name: post_status
  - name: created

- kind: posts
  properties:
  - name: post_status
  - name: created
    direction: desc
```

Any idea on how to speed up the process?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do to speed up indexing is to create indexes when you have less data - though this will impose additional overhead on inserts. Other than that, you have to leave it up to the automated system to build the indexes as fast as it can.

Comment: Its taking queit a lot of time to serve index even when I deploy application with no data in the datastore. Any ideas?

Comment: The index build queue is shared by all apps, so at busy times even an empty index will take a while to build. This shouldn't matter a great deal, though, as you should only have to build new indexes relatively infrequently.